# Position SCNNode in front of camera with just one axis of rotation

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to make an ARKit application where an SCNNode, in this case a box, is placed in front of the camera, facing the camera. As the user moves the camera around, objects are placed when a certain distance has been moved. This would leave you with a series of nodes facing the camera in a line, equally spaced.

I have this working to a certain extent, but my problem is with the rotation. I'm currently taking all axes of rotation, so as the user re-orients their phone, the rotation of the node matches. I want to restrict this to just the rotation around the y-axis. The ideal outcome is a domino-trail like look, with all the objects having the same x and z rotations, but potentially different y rotations.

I hope I've explained this clearly enough!

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
func createNode(fromCameraTransform cameraTransform: matrix_float4x4) -> SCNNode {
    let geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.02, height: 0.04, length: 0.01, chamferRadius: 0)

    let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: geometry))
    physicsBody.mass = 1000

    let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
    node.physicsBody = physicsBody

    var translationMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4
    translationMatrix.columns.3.x = 0.05  // Moves the node down in world space
    translationMatrix.columns.3.z = -0.1  // Moves the object away from the camera

    node.simdTransform = simd_mul(cameraTransform, translationMatrix)

    return node
}
```

I've tried different combinations of extracting values from the second column of the `cameraTransform` and setting them as `eulerAngles`, `rotation` and `simdRotation`, but to no avail.

I've also tried extracting values from the `pointOfView` of the current `sceneView` and assigning them to the same values as listed above, but again, no luck.

Any help would greatly appreciated!

I know a little bit about this, but am really just starting out with SceneKit and 3D transformations/matrices so be gentle with me!

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what your trying to do, basically automatically drop each new domino so its evenly spaced following the camera.pointOfView trail.

You can update the new nodes euler angles y-axis to the same as the cameras pointofView eularAngles.y. So as you move the camera around the next node you are placing is always facing towards the camera (only rotating around the y-axis).

[image]

The renderer function updateAtTime below gets called everytime
the camera moves

```
  func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {


// You set the camera’s pointOfView’s eularAngle for y-xis to the node you are 
   about to place.

node.eulerAngles.y = (sceneView.pointOfView?.eulerAngles.y)!
```

- I had this working in a playground so it does work.

Edit: This solution above angle was having a gimbal lock problem (as you went around in a circle in would reset its angle back to the axis.

So I found this approach using SCNBillboardConstraint works without experiencing the gimbal lock problem as you go around in circle.

```
let yFreeConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
                yFreeConstraint.freeAxes = .Y 
                node.constraints = [yFreeConstraint]
                node.eulerAngles = node.presentation.eulerAngles
                node.position = position
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Will try this out and let you know how I get on

Comment: It works, but `orientation` keeps zero value, so, if you then need that's angles, this is useless

Comment: Your comment is too vague to decipher. It works but it useless? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408030-presentation